# Sympy: get a column of a matrix power

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

This seems to be a simple question. My code reads

```
import sympy as sp
D1 = sp.symbols('D1')
D2 = sp.symbols('D2')
m1 = sp.diag(*[2 * D1, 2 * D1, 2 * D2, 2 * D2])
b = sp.sqrt(m1)

m1.col(0)
b.col(0)
```

I.e. I want to get a column of the square root of a matrix. However, it seems like the `MatPow` object `b` does not have the `.col` attribute, which normal matrices like `m1` have.

Output:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-855c6e53a412> in <module>()
----> 1 b.col(0)

AttributeError: 'MatPow' object has no attribute 'col'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `MatPow` object to `MutableDenseMatrix` with `as_mutable` method:

```
b_as_m = b.as_mutable()
print(b_as_m.col(0))
```

Output:

```
Matrix([[sqrt(2)*sqrt(D1)], [0], [0], [0]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I mark this answer as accepted, but could you explain why this is not done automatically?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś I guess it is because of possible optimizations. For example if you try to calculate `(m1 ** 0.5) ** 2` sympy can return `m1` without actual calculation of `temp = m1 ** 0.5` and `result = temp ** 2`.

Comment: True, but this does not explain why one cannot take a column of a matrix-like object...

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś there is some kind of lazy evaluation. Matrix-like object `b` is not a fully evaluated matrix - values of it's columns are not defined now. It is only known that `b = m1 ** 0.5`. To know the values you need to evaluate it first with `as_mutable`.